# BitBucket fails to open SourceTree pop up screen when attempting to check out project

Tags: bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

MacOS Mojave 10.14.1
SourceTree 3.0.1 (205)
Both Safari and Chrome

---

When I access my corporate BitBucket and attempt to checkout in SourceTree, the check out pop up does not open. The action will open the SourceTree app if it is not already running. No difference in behavior by having SourceTree open before accessing BitBucket.

SourceTree is still working with already checked out projects. I can commit and it is correctly reporting updates that I need to pull down. I am not being asked for my credentials and no errors are being displayed in either the web screen or from the SourceTree app.

As far as I know I am the only one in my organization having this issue.

In checking the logs below, I do see that one Err(16) but I can't find anything explaining it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

LWhite

Here are the logs from console searching for SourceTree during a failed attempt.

default 16:06:31.046146 -0500 Sourcetree Requesting sharingServicesForItems: mask:6

default 16:06:31.046370 -0500 Sourcetree filteredItemsFromItems: [48048]-->

default 16:06:31.047439 -0500 Sourcetree Discover

default 16:06:31.051713 -0500 Sourcetree discovery complete: 1 plugins

default 16:06:31.052317 -0500 Sourcetree Discover done

default 16:06:31.052358 -0500 Sourcetree Discover

default 16:06:31.065315 -0500 Sourcetree discovery complete: 4 plugins

default 16:06:31.065416 -0500 Sourcetree Discover done

default 16:06:31.065600 -0500 Sourcetree services:

default 16:06:31.065653 -0500 Sourcetree Requesting sharingServicesForItems: mask:6

default 16:06:31.065817 -0500 Sourcetree filteredItemsFromItems: [48048]-->

default 16:06:31.066333 -0500 Sourcetree Discover

default 16:06:31.070421 -0500 Sourcetree discovery complete: 1 plugins

default 16:06:31.071006 -0500 Sourcetree Discover done

default 16:06:31.071038 -0500 Sourcetree Discover

default 16:06:31.082844 -0500 Sourcetree discovery complete: 4 plugins

default 16:06:31.082947 -0500 Sourcetree Discover done

default 16:06:31.083138 -0500 Sourcetree services:

default 16:06:31.083183 -0500 Sourcetree Requesting sharingServicesForItems: mask:6

default 16:06:31.083486 -0500 Sourcetree filteredItemsFromItems: [48048]-->

default 16:06:31.084073 -0500 Sourcetree Discover

default 16:06:31.087559 -0500 Sourcetree discovery complete: 1 plugins

default 16:06:31.087959 -0500 Sourcetree Discover done

default 16:06:31.087993 -0500 Sourcetree Discover

default 16:06:31.097711 -0500 Sourcetree discovery complete: 4 plugins

default 16:06:31.097780 -0500 Sourcetree Discover done

default 16:06:31.097942 -0500 Sourcetree services:

default 16:06:31.227729 -0500 Sourcetree Task .<1> resuming, QOS(0x9)

default 16:06:31.228269 -0500 Sourcetree Task .<1> {strength 0, tls 4, ct 0, sub 0, sig 1, ciphers 0, bundle 0, builtin 0}

default 16:06:31.228538 -0500 Sourcetree TIC Enabling TLS [10:0x7fd4b6681770]

default 16:06:31.228587 -0500 Sourcetree TIC TCP Conn Start [10:0x7fd4b6681770]

default 16:06:31.228729 -0500 Sourcetree [C10 Hostname#220da288:443 tcp, url: https://e.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/events, tls] start

default 16:06:31.229083 -0500 Sourcetree nw_connection_report_state_with_handler_locked [C10] reporting state preparing

default 16:06:31.229686 -0500 Sourcetree Task .<1> setting up Connection 10

default 16:06:31.266032 -0500 Sourcetree nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C10.1:3] Socket received CONNECTED event

default 16:06:31.266144 -0500 Sourcetree nw_endpoint_flow_protocol_connected [C10.1 IPv4#a9d1e55d:443 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] Transport protocol connected

default 16:06:31.267763 -0500 Sourcetree TIC TLS Event [10:0x7fd4b6681770]: 1, Pending(0)

default 16:06:31.267897 -0500 Sourcetree TIC TLS Event [10:0x7fd4b6681770]: 2, Pending(0)

default 16:06:31.294615 -0500 Sourcetree TIC TLS Event [10:0x7fd4b6681770]: 2, Pending(0)

default 16:06:31.296829 -0500 Sourcetree TIC TLS Event [10:0x7fd4b6681770]: 11, Pending(0)

default 16:06:31.297169 -0500 Sourcetree TIC TLS Event [10:0x7fd4b6681770]: 14, Pending(0)

default 16:06:31.332502 -0500 Sourcetree TIC TLS Trust Result [10:0x7fd4b6681770]: 0

default 16:06:31.359758 -0500 Sourcetree nw_endpoint_flow_protocol_connected [C10.1 IPv4#a9d1e55d:443 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] Output protocol connected

default 16:06:31.360072 -0500 Sourcetree nw_connection_report_state_with_handler_locked [C10] reporting state ready

default 16:06:31.360531 -0500 Sourcetree TIC TLS Event [10:0x7fd4b6681770]: 20, Pending(0)

default 16:06:31.360571 -0500 Sourcetree TIC TCP Conn Connected [10:0x7fd4b6681770]: Err(16)

default 16:06:31.360811 -0500 Sourcetree TIC TCP Conn Event [10:0x7fd4b6681770]: 1

default 16:06:31.360848 -0500 Sourcetree TIC TCP Conn Event [10:0x7fd4b6681770]: 8

default 16:06:31.360884 -0500 Sourcetree TIC TLS Handshake Complete [10:0x7fd4b6681770]

default 16:06:31.361234 -0500 Sourcetree Task .<1> now using Connection 10

default 16:06:31.361434 -0500 Sourcetree nw_endpoint_flow_protocol_connected [C10.1 IPv4#a9d1e55d:443 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] Output protocol connected

default 16:06:31.361961 -0500 Sourcetree Task .<1> sent request, body S

default 16:06:31.388733 -0500 Sourcetree Task .<1> received response, status 200 content K

default 16:06:31.388845 -0500 Sourcetree Task .<1> response ended

default 16:06:31.388935 -0500 Sourcetree Task .<1> done using Connection 10

default 16:06:37.446828 -0500 Sourcetree 27366555: RECEIVED OUT-OF-SEQUENCE NOTIFICATION: 0 vs 1958, 513,

default 16:06:37.549591 -0500 Sourcetree Task <286E9269-50FF-4EF7-8F19-223634797BCF>.<2> resuming, QOS(0x9)

default 16:06:37.549965 -0500 Sourcetree Task <286E9269-50FF-4EF7-8F19-223634797BCF>.<2> {strength 0, tls 4, ct 0, sub 0, sig 1, ciphers 0, bundle 0, builtin 0}

default 16:06:37.550090 -0500 Sourcetree Task <286E9269-50FF-4EF7-8F19-223634797BCF>.<2> now using Connection 10

default 16:06:37.550638 -0500 Sourcetree Task <286E9269-50FF-4EF7-8F19-223634797BCF>.<2> sent request, body S

default 16:06:37.578410 -0500 Sourcetree Task <286E9269-50FF-4EF7-8F19-223634797BCF>.<2> received response, status 200 content K

default 16:06:37.578503 -0500 Sourcetree Task <286E9269-50FF-4EF7-8F19-223634797BCF>.<2> response ended

default 16:06:37.578568 -0500 Sourcetree Task <286E9269-50FF-4EF7-8F19-223634797BCF>.<2> done using Connection 10

L

Answer (score 0):

I received the following response from Atlassian.

---

We've had a smattering of reports about reciprocal links still not working properly with 3.0.1. I'll make sure we investigate for an upcoming release but can't state an ETA currently.

In the meantime you should be able to list your company's repositories in the Repositories Browser under the Remote tab, filtering by name using the search field, and then clicking the Clone button there.

Brian Ganninger
Senior Mac Developer, Sourcetree

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/BitBucket-fails-to-open-SourceTree-pop-up-screen-when-attempting/qaq-p/949285